# jquery callback on click to perform another click

Tags: jquery

I have a series of clicks:

```
    console.log('1')
    $('.tool-projects').click()
    console.log('2')
    $('#drawer-projects > ul > li > div > div.tool > div.jellybean-container.jelly-beans > span > input.typeahead.tt-input').click(function() {
    console.log('3')
    var project = 'attribution'
    $('.suggestion-value:contains('+project+')').click()
    console.log('4')
    $('.btn-primary')[0].click();
```

and I want for the page to wait for one click to finish before moving on to the second.
I tried this to no avail.

```
            $('.tool-projects').click(function() {
                console.log('2')
                $('#drawer-projects > ul > li > div > div.tool > div.jellybean-container.jelly-beans > span > input.typeahead.tt-input').click(function() {
                    console.log('3')
                    var project = 'attribution'
                    $('.suggestion-value:contains('+project+')').click(function() {
                        console.log('4')
                        $('.btn-primary')[0].click();            
                    });        
                })    
            });
```

This just prints out `1`. I looked at the documentation - https://api.jquery.com/click/

```
.click( handler )
handler
Type: Function( Event eventObject )
A function to execute each time the event is triggered.
```

I thought my solution would work, maybe I just misunderstood how to implement it? Is there a way to have a callback on a click?

To explain why I need to do this:

clicking `.tools-projects` opens a drop down menu
until that's clicked, `'#drawer-projects'` doesn't exist. Once that does exist, I need to click it which opens the `.suggestion-value` dropdown menu, so I can access the project `attribution`

Comment: Every new click event handler will exist and process **the next click** that happens for the element.  If you are creating a click event handler due to a click happening, the second click handler will not immediately execute.  It will wait for the next event.

Comment: However, to avoid an XY Problem, please explain why you need to force asynchronous click logic into a synchronous pattern?

Comment: It looks like you're confusing event *triggers* with event *handlers* - each click *trigger* `$(..).click()` will complete before the next line of code is executed.  If the click handler `$(..).click(function { .. })` has any *asynchronous* code then the click handler will return before that has completed.  You need to handle asynchronous calls differently from "waiting for it to complete" (and certainly not by adding new *handlers*).

Comment: As you've not included whether the click handlers make any ajax calls, this can only be a guidance - if they do, have a read of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: From your own link: *This method is a shortcut for .on( "click", handler ) in the first two variations, and **.trigger( "click" ) in the third**.*

Comment: @Taplar added explanation